# How to access helm programmatically

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm

I'd like to access cluster deployed Helm charts programmatically to make web interface which will allow manual chart manipulation.

I found [pyhelm](https://pypi.org/project/pyhelm) but it supports only Helm 2. I looked on npm, but nothing there. I wrote a bash script but if I try to use it's output I get just a string really so it's not really useful.

Comment: Do you mean editing charts in a chart _repository_ or deployed applications?

Comment: Sorry - I meant "within deployed applications". Effectively I'd like to get the list of what is deployed and show it on the website. Later, add delete button and delete the applications installed on the cluster.

Answer (score 4):

> I'd like to access cluster deployed Helm charts programmatically to make web interface which will allow manual chart manipulation.

[Helm 3 is different](https://helm.sh/blog/helm-3-released/) than previous versions in that it is a **client only** tool, similar to e.g. [Kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/). This means that *helm charts* only exists on the client (and in chart repositories) but is then *transformed* to a *kubernetes manifest* during deployment. So only *Kubernetes objects* exists in the cluster.

[Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#deployment-v1-apps) is a REST API so you can access and get Kubernetes objects using a http client. Kubernetes object manifests is available in JSON and Yaml formats.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does this mean I can do something that would look something like `kubectl get helm applications`? Essentially I'd like to get a json with the same that `helm list` gives, but in go, python, dart or any other language.

Comment: To list applications you use `kubectl get deployments` and to list revisions you can use `kubectl get replicasets` and you can also use _labels_  and _selectors_ to filter subsets. It all depends on what you really want to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you are OK to use Go then you can use the [Helm 3 Go API](https://pkg.go.dev/helm.sh/helm/v3).

If you want to use Python, I guess you'll have to wait for the Helm v3 support of [pyhelm](https://pypi.org/project/pyhelm), there is already [an issue](https://github.com/flaper87/pyhelm/issues/84) addressing this.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how to install this and an any example of usage? I never used Go lang before and for some reason any attempt using `go get xxx` fails. I am not sure why :/

Comment: If you don't know Go at all I guess it would be better to helm pyhelm supporting Helm v3 or you use the Helm CLI with "-o json" and parse the output in your Python webapp

Comment: Python supports only helm 2. I did actually manage to get data using `-o json`, but this way I am unable to provide access keys to the app, which means that the app is tightly coupled with environment it's running in. I did a guide on go page and managed to install various packages - not the one for helm... Not sure what I'm supposed to install. Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Adam It's been a year, but here's example usage of the Helm Go SDK: https://helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#go-sdk

Answer (score -1):

reached this as we also need an npm package to deploy helm3 charts programmatically (sorta whitelabel app  with a gui to manage the instances).

Only thing I could find was an old discontinued package from microsoft for helm v2 https://github.com/microsoft/helm-web-api/tree/master/on-demand-micro-services-deployment-k8s

I dont think using k8s API would work, as some charts can get fairly complex in terms of k8s resources, so I got some inspiration and I think I will develop my own package as a wrapper to the helm cli commands, using `-o json` param for easier handling of the CLI output